# Установка vk_api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, pip

При установки `vk_api` на `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` выдетает ошибка установки.

```
pip install vk_api
Collecting vk_api
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/c6/7ab7b58b00c6b06af38ce244515e4c6ad6b8fae0c00d4931c63bcdc803f3/vk_api-11.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-a21j4lkr/vk-api/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        long_description = f.read()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 193: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-a21j4lkr/vk-api/
```

Какие варианты ее устранить

Comment: egg_info - это ключевое сообщение в вашей ошибке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить библиотеку не через pip, а скачав архив с файлами библиотеки и запустить файл setup.py
https://github.com/python273/vk_api

Если ошибка будет та же то в начале setup.py добавьте

```
import sys
from importlib import reload
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Это может вам помочь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal

Также посмотрите это

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473681/pip-install-numpy-throws-an-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2